# Including Cypress config file into docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, cypress

I am following this [article](https://mtlynch.io/painless-web-app-testing/) to run Cypress test with Docker.

I encountered issue where I need `cypress.json` file to be included in `docker-compose.yaml`. Here is example of my `docker-compose.yaml`file looks like

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  cypress:
    image: "cypress/included:7.7.0"
    enviroment:
    - HTTP_PROXY=somekind_url
    working_dir: location of cypress files
    volumes:
    - ./:/cypress
    command: [-b, chrome]
```

My question is how to tell in `docker-compose.yaml` to grab my `cypress.json` that is located in root project directory?

Answer (score 2):

You can see how in https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-example-docker-compose-included/blob/master/docker-compose.yml

```
   volumes:
      - ./cypress:/cypress
      - ./cypress.json:/cypress.json
```

`./cypress.json` it's your local file, and `/cypress.json` it's the file into the container.